# Missing FM radio functionality in CyanogenMod on Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300)

Tags: cyanogenmod, fm-radio

I installed CyanogenMod 13 on my i9300 and noticed there is no radio app any more.

How can I get the functionality back?

Comment: opinion-based question

Comment: Which parts are opinionated? I'll delete or change them.

Comment: the whole question, _"Free FM radio app for samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300)?"_, is off-topic? ASking for recommendations

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575).

Comment: @Izzy I removed SW recommendation parts from the question.

Comment: @DavidBalažic that's "camouflaging" – as it's pretty clear you need an app for that (and you know it). Have you checked the pointers I gave with the links in my last comment?

Comment: @Izzy Of course I have. I also posted a SW recommendation question there. As for here, I stated the problem I have. What rule is it still violating? The "need for SW" is just your assumption. For example CM has a built-in compass. If someone would ask "how to find north" you might "judge" it to be a SW recommendation question when in fact it is not. Anyway, if you think my problem has nothing lost here, just delete it. I think it is stated very clearly, but if not, ask.

Comment: Ah, yes: your question at SR just popped up (and well fits). Let's leave it at that. I'm not the entire community – so if people vote to reopen your question here, so it shall be. I've explained my reasoning.